# Usage of HasNoDiscriminator in EFCore

Tags: c#, entity-framework-core

I am working on EntityFrameworkCore.Cosmo provider and encountered `HasNoDiscriminator` method.
What is the usage of keeping the below code?

```
 modelBuilder.Entity<Patient>().HasNoDiscriminator();
```

Answer (score 4):

It's a Cosmos-specific model customization.

> To identify the entity type that a given item represent EF Core adds a
>   discriminator value even if there are no derived entity types. The
>   name and value of the discriminator can be changed.
>
> If no other entity type will ever be stored in the same container the
>   discriminator can be removed by calling HasNoDiscriminator.

Source : [Cosmos-specific model customization](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/providers/cosmos/?tabs=dotnet-core-cli#cosmos-specific-model-customization)

I suspect that the goal is to prevent another entity than Patient from being stored in the container.